# Can I sacrifice creatures that are attacking before they are blocked?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I declare my attackers as two 1/1 goblins, and my opponent declares his blockers as two 2/2 cards, before the creatures deal damage to each other, can I sacrifice my goblins to [Goblin Bombardment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397584)? The 2/2 cards would still have 2 toughness before [Goblin Bombardment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397584) triggered. None of the abilities require attacking as a trigger, so let's just say I was "testing the waters" and if one of my goblins was blocked, I would have sacrificed it and the other would have attacked.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about what exactly you are asking? Do you just want to know whether you can sacrifice a blocked attacker to Goblin Bombardment before damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can sacrifice one of you attackers after blockers but before combat damage.

> 116.1b A player may activate an activated ability any time he or she has priority.
>
> 116.3a The active player receives priority at the beginning of most steps and phases, after any turn-based actions (such as drawing a card during the draw step; see rule 703) have been dealt with and abilities that trigger at the beginning of that phase or step have been put on the stack. No player receives priority during the untap step. Players usually don’t get priority during the cleanup step (see rule 514.3).

At this moment you are the active player and will receive priority after the declare blockers step. Now that you have priority you may activate an activated ability, so you can activate your Goblin Bombardment and sacrifice one of your creatures to kill one of your oponents blockers, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In the Declare Blockers Step, after declaring blockers, players get priority:

> [509.5.](https://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Game+Rules#2826) Fifth, the active player gets priority. Players may cast spells and activate abilities.

Goblin Bombardment has an activated ability (indicated by the colon), which you are allowed to activate:

> [116.1b](https://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Game+Rules#2573) A player may activate an activated ability any time he or she has priority.